# Recursive function to check linkedlist size inside a leaf

Tags: c, tree

I am dealing with a ternary tree. It its a little unique in the sense that each leaf contains a pointer to a linkedlist and the linkedlist maintains a size (representing number of nodes).

Here is the Structures in my code to give you some idea.

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H_
#define VARIABLES_H_

struct data
{
  int val;
};




struct node
{
  struct node* next;
  struct data* dta;
};

struct linkedList
{
  int size;
  struct node *head;
};

struct leaf
{
  struct linkedList* ll;
  struct leaf* left;
  struct leaf* right;
  struct leaf* center;
  struct leaf* parent;
};

struct tree
{
  struct leaf* root;
};


#endif
```

I am trying to write a function that returns 1 if all the leafs in a tree have a linkedlist of size 3 and 0 otherwise.

This is what i have so far.

```
int isFullList(struct tree *tr)
{
  if(tr->root == NULL)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    return isFullList_r(tr->root);
  }
}

int isFullList_r(struct leaf *lf)
{
  if(lf==NULL){return 1;}
  if(lf->ll->size == 3){return 1;}
  if(lf->ll->size != 3){return 0;}   

  return isFullList_r(lf->left) && isFullList_r(lf->center) && isFullList_r(lf->right);
}
```

However i am not getting the right answer as it always keeps returning 1. Can someone point out why and how to fix this?

Comment: Because in the depth-first walk of each subtree it eventually hits a NULL. You have to watch out for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive function needs to handle the actual leafs (end points of the tree), as well as checking each node's linked-list length.

```
int isFullList_r(struct leaf *lf)
{

  // End condition for passing in NULL leafs
  if(lf == NULL){ return 1;}

  if(lf->ll==NULL){return 0;} // Not size 3
  if(lf->ll->size != 3){return 0;}  //Not size 3 

  if(lf->ll->size == 3){return 
      isFullList_r(lf->left) && isFullList_r(lf->center) && isFullList_r(lf->right);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something doesn't sound right in the function `isFullList_r`

```
int isFullList_r(struct leaf *lf)
{
  if(lf==NULL){return 1;}

  // if>ll->size is 3, you return here.
  if(lf->ll->size == 3){return 1;}

  // if>ll->size is not 3, you return here. 
  if(lf->ll->size != 3){return 0;}   

  // The code never gets here.
  return isFullList_r(lf->left) && isFullList_r(lf->center) && isFullList_r(lf->right);
}
```

Your statement *I am trying to write a function that returns 1 if all the leafs in a tree have a linkedlist of size 3 and 0 otherwise.* doesn't sound logical. Some of the `leaf`s are bound to have less than 3 items. That's how the tree ends.